# How to prevent checkbox to be selected when click anywhere on row?

Tags: angular, selection, angular7, mat-table

my row get selected when i click anywhere on the row even my radio button and slide toggle, i want it to be selected only when user clicks on checkbox

```js
selection: SelectionModel<aproveTable> = new SelectionModel<aproveTable>(true, []);
@Output() approveSelectEvent: EventEmitter<aproveTable[]> = new EventEmitter<aproveTable[]>();
ngOnInit() {
        this.selection.changed.asObservable().subscribe(
            (value: SelectionChange<aproveTable>) => {
                this.approveSelectEvent.emit(this.selection.selected);
        });
    }
```

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">

                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                </td>

</ng-container>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the stackblitz?

Comment: Using $event.stopPropagation():
```<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation();"></mat-checkbox>```

Comment: @mojtabaramezani its still not working i added (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" but same output

Comment: @PrashantPimpale here is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzqj51

Comment: @HUSSAIN Found this:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2042

Comment: thanks @PrashantPimpale but when i am using ```stopPropagation()``` on all the td  my checkbox no more selecting the row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From below line:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
</tr>
```

Remove:

```
(click)="selection.toggle(row)" -- remove this
```

by that, you are telling angular, whenever you click row selection has to be changed.

and

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="changeSelection(row)" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
</mat-checkbox>
```

write this, that only checkbox toggled selection, here's changeSelection method,

```
changeSelection(row){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.selection.toggle(row);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your stackblitz example I could see the error.
You are making an extra toggle of the selection in the line 78 `(click)="selection.toggle(row)"`, just get rid of it:

```
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
```

**Live example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55862476-materialrow?file=app/table-selection-example.html

Answer (score 0):

to use (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" on th and td helps. but here should be some more logical way